# coffeekup as view engine with express 3

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, express, coffeekup

I'm trying to use coffeekup as my default template

```
app.set 'view engine', 'coffee'
app.register '.coffee', coffeekup.adapters.express
```

except app.register isn't a function it looks like.  whats the migration?

Comment: I ended up creating my own 'loadDir' function, which loads a dir, runs it through a compiler, and either requires it or writes it to a new directory.  In this case, I run it through the coffeecup compiler and stick it into a template object

Comment: use the npm module `loaddir` it is pretty awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want `app.engine` instead of `app.register` -- the guide needs to be updated.

Check out the unit tests for examples:
https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/test/app.engine.js

Comment: This leads to "Error: callback function required", because coffeekup.adapters.express is an object, not a function.

Comment: whatever `npm install coffeekup` installs.

Answer (score 2):

coffeekup was Changed to 'coffeecup'

follow this link : https://github.com/gradus/coffeecup

Answer (score 2):

coffeecup derivative [teacup has an up to date example](http://goodeggs.github.com/teacup/#getting-started/express)